# Rich text editor Redactor adding additional paragraph p tags

Tags: redactor

The rich text editor redactor is adding in additional p tags to rich text content. Is there a way to modify this so it accepts the unmodified HTML but still has the advantage of WYSIWYG editing?

Perhaps it is fixed in version 10.0.1 as I see Craft uses v9.2.6 of this editor. Will it be upgraded perhaps to test?

**Update**: This seems to be part of the config: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-replaceDivs

**I believe we should be able to turn on/off some things**. e.g. http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-removeEmpty http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-paragraphize

Comment: Do I get this right, you want to enter/edit HTML code in rich text fields?

Comment: Nup - I can do that already. The problem is toggling between code/wysiwyg is adding p tags in place of my div tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-replaceDivs
http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-removeEmpty http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-paragraphize

Standard.json

```
{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video', 'table'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen'],
    toolbarFixedBox: true,
    paragraphize: false,
    replaceDivs: false
}
```

**Edit**: This bug also happens in the most recent version of Redactor [as seen on their example page](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/source/).